# Could not access file:....Sending pdf in a email attachment

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Im using php mailer class to send emails and it is working fine.

But now im trying to send an attachment in my email and Im having an error.

When I click in my button to send email I get my sucess message that email was sent with sucess but I also get this message "**Could not access file: pdfName.pdf**".

In my file to send emails I have this **php code**:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sendForm'])){
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $pdf = $_FILES['pdf']['name'];


    if(empty($subject) || empty($_FILES['pdf']['name'])){
        echo 'Please fill all fields';
    }
    else{
        $readSubscribers = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM subscribers");  
        $readSubscribers->execute();

        if($readSubscribers->rowCount() <=0){
            echo 'We dont have any subscriber yet.';    
        }
        else{
            while($result = $readSubscribers->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $email  = $result['email'];
            $code = md5($code);
            $msg = 'email message';  
            sendMail($subject,$msg,MAILUSER,SITENAME,$email,'',$pdf);
            }
            echo 'Email sent with sucess.';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And this is **my html**:

```
<form name="editpost" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <div>
        <span>Subject:</span>
        <input type="text" name="subject" value="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Attachment:</span>
        <input type="file" name="pdf" accept="application/pdf" />                         
    </div>  
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="sendForm"/>
</form>
```

Also If I store my pdf lime temporary file, like this:

```
$pdf = $_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'];
```

I dont have any error message when I click in my button to send email, but when I receive the email email have this name: "phpF.tmp", and its impossible to open...

Comment: rename your tempfile to something like `$_FILES['pdf']['name']`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Raphael Muller. But Im trying with $_FILES['pdf']['name'], and I get the error "Could not access file: pdfName.pdf". I just test ['tmp_name'] to see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your send php file:

```
//first rename the uploaded file:

$filename = "/tmp/".$_FILES['pdf']['name'];
rename($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'], $filename);

//you can also move the uploaded file with the command:
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'], $filename);

...

//and then send the changed file
sendMail($subject, $msg, MAILUSER, SITENAME, $email, '', $filename);

//and if everything is fine delete the file:
unlink($filename);
```

ADDITION:

you can check if the uploaded file is from type pdf:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name']) && strtolower(substr($_FILES['pdf']['name'], -4)) == ".pdf")
{
    //and do something if the file is uploaded:
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'], $filename)
    {

    }
}

//or check the mimetype
ob_start();
$type = system("file --mime-type -b ".$filename);
ob_clean();
```

Comment: Thanks Raphael Muller. Your solution worked perfectly!